# App crashing with error: -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash

This line `[self.label setFont:[MyUtilityClass fontWithSize:13.0f]];` of code is giving me the -[NSNull length]: crash. `label` as many of you guys can guess is a UILabel. The only logical explanation I can think of is UILabel text is null.  I will post my utility class below just in case it helps.

MyUtilityClass

```
 + (UIFont *) fontWithSize : (CGFloat) size
   {
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:size];

return font;
    }
```

edit: This is the error message I've received. I can copy and paste the raw data if you need me to. This is a crash a user received according to crashlytics.

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

```
  -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x378e23f0
```

This is the raw data of the crash.

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x297c3c1f __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x36f97c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x297c9039 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x297c6f57 ___forwarding___ + 714
4  CoreFoundation                 0x296f8df8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5  UIKit                          0x2cc8b1b5 -[UILabel _setFont:] + 100
6  MyApp                        0x00137c29 -[MyViewController initUI] (MyViewController.m:90)
7  MyApp                       0x0013765b -[MyViewController viewDidLoad] (MyViewController.m:51)
8  UIKit                          0x2cc82f8f -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
9  UIKit                          0x2cd2cd95 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 32
10 UIKit                          0x2cd2ccbd -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 228
11 UIKit                          0x2cd2c253 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 74
12 UIKit                          0x2cd2bf83 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 578
13 UIKit                          0x2cd2bced -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 44
14 UIKit                          0x2cd2bc81 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 184
15 UIKit                          0x2cc804d7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 514
16 QuartzCore                     0x2c6a8a0d -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 136
17 QuartzCore                     0x2c6a43e5 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
18 QuartzCore                     0x2c6a426d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
19 QuartzCore                     0x2c6a3c51 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
20 QuartzCore                     0x2c6a3a55 CA::Transaction::commit() + 324
21 UIKit                          0x2cc78965 _afterCACommitHandler + 132
22 CoreFoundation                 0x2978a3b5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
23 CoreFoundation                 0x29787a73 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278
24 CoreFoundation                 0x29787e7b __CFRunLoopRun + 914
25 CoreFoundation                 0x296d6211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
26 CoreFoundation                 0x296d6023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
27 GraphicsServices               0x30a8f0a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
28 UIKit                          0x2cce21d1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
29 MyApp                        0x000a07e7 main (main.m:16)
30 libdyld.dylib                  0x37517aaf start + 2
```

Comment: NSNull is not the same as nil. You need to ask yourself how on earth an NSNull got into the story. Did you write code that uses it? You probably shouldn't; it is very rarely needed for anything.

Comment: Copy/paste the exact and full error message into the question.

Comment: Are you sure the right dSYM file was used to symbolicate?

Comment: Does this application pull in JSON data? are you checking your incoming data for `[NSNull null]` values?

Comment: Your error does not appear to be in the code you have provided (since that doesn't try to send the `length` message to anything)

Comment: Please post the full symbolicated stack trace. This will show where the error is.

Comment: Add the "All Exceptions" breakpoint and tell us where the problem really lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very likely that you are trying to get the length of what you think is an `NSString` but is actually `NSNull`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue with my code & resolved it by using system fonts. The case was it couldn't load the font which I had specified into the code. Try & let me know if it help.

Happy Coding, cheers,
Ratneshwar